# PSR-2 CodeSniffer standard for eclipse plugin PHP_CodeSniffer

Tags: php, eclipse, code-standards, phpcodesniffer

I'm using this eclipse plugin (http://www.phpsrc.org/projects/pti-php-codesniffer/wiki/) to check PHP code style.

This plugin comes with some standards to check, but no with PSR-2.

This plugin lets define a custom standard by giving a file.

I've donwload this psr2 standard (https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/tree/master/CodeSniffer/Standards/PSR2) and defined in eclipse plugin like a custom standard.

But it doesn't work (eclipse is not telling me any error I have). It does if I configure a no custom standard (a plugin included standard).

Anyone with this problem? Any other way to configure eclipse to tell me (while I'm coding) where are PSR-2 non compliance code?

Comment: Is it a question about code or about Eclipse configuration?

Comment: Hi AlexKM, it's about Eclipse configuration (to test PHP code)

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure this question was on-topic here but according to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it's the right place.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pdt-extensions-platform/VHmprqQ9pvg), the PSR-2 standard is defined in a Symfony plugin ([which I assume to be this one](http://symfony.dubture.com/)). So, rather than make your own, you could use someone else's.

Side note: This may not be the *best* answer as it probably comes with overhead you don't need if you're not using Symfony.

**Added:** [Potential alternative here](https://github.com/wcomnisky/php-formatter), but it looks like it's only been tested in Zend Studio, not PDT